# how to create a warning for the user in C/GTK+3

Tags: c, dialog, gtk3

This is the main program of a my project.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if(!gcry_check_version(GCRYPT_MIN_VER)){
        fputs("libgcrypt min version required: 1.5.0\n", stderr);
        return -1;
    }
    gcry_control(GCRYCTL_INIT_SECMEM, 16384, 0);
    gcry_control(GCRYCTL_INITIALIZATION_FINISHED, 0);

    const gchar *ret = glib_check_version(2, 36, 0);
    if(ret != NULL){
        printf("%s\n", ret);
        return -1;
    }

    setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
    bindtextdomain(PACKAGE, LOCALE_DIR);
    textdomain(PACKAGE);

    GtkApplication *app;
    int status;
    GError *err = NULL;
    GdkPixbuf *logo = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file(icon, &err);
    gtk_window_set_default_icon(logo);

    app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example",G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
    g_signal_connect (app, "startup", G_CALLBACK (startup), NULL);
    g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
    status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
    g_object_unref (app);
    return status;
}
```

The function `startup` create a g_menu with 2 entries while the function `activate` create the window, the grid and 2 buttons (encrypt, decrypt). When the "encrypt" button is clicked the function `do_enc` is called. Inside this function a dialog with 2 gtk_entry (type pwd and retype pwd) and 2 buttons (close and ok) is created.
My problem is that the encryption can take long time if the file is very large so i need to give the user an info (like "hey, wait some minutes"). I thought to use a `gtk_message_dialog_new` or a `gtk_info_bar_new` but i am not able to show them because the function `gtk_widget_show` does nothing outside the main xD
I saw that there are `g_timeout_add` and `g_idle_add` that could be used to call from inside the main the function but i have no idea about how to use them (and honestly i think that it isn't a good idea to continuosly call the function `do_enc`)..
So I don't know how to show this warning. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "gtk_widget_show does nothing outside the main"? Do you mean outside the main thread? If you don't use threads, probably your problem is simply that do_enc is already blocking the main loop and that's why your window is not shown (unless you use gtk_main_iteration).

Comment: i'm not using thread :) using gtk_main_iteration the widget is displayed but i read that spinning the event loop manually is not recommended because it means i'm exposing myself to re-entrancy issues

Comment: So you're left with threads. Maybe [this page](http://blog.borovsak.si/2009/06/multi-threaded-gtk-applications.html) can be of some help.